# Cypress executable not found at: /root/.cache/Cypress/3.8.3/Cypress/Cypress

Tags: angular, docker, npm, jenkins-pipeline, cypress

I am getting this error 'Cypress executable not found at: /root/.cache/Cypress/3.8.3/Cypress/Cypress' when the cypress command 'npx cypress run -P projects/demoProject-cypress' is run on docker at cloud. This is a command written in jenkins to run before deployment. I have tried wait-on but it is not useful. This is a angular project on npm.

Help!

Comment: 'No version of Cypress is installed in: /root/.cache/Cypress/3.8.3/Cypress' : this also an error

Answer (score 3):

Set `CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER` environment variable.

Ex on Linux:

```
export CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER=/custom_path/cypress
```

When you install `Cypress` it's caching some binaries and stuff. Usually, for a regular user, default cache locations are as follows.

```
MacOS: ~/Library/Caches/Cypress
Linux: ~/.cache/Cypress
Windows: /AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache
```

When `CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER` env variable is set Cypress resources will be cached to that location and when running, Cypress will find stuff there. Make sure the user has access to the cache location.

Answer (score 1):

your npx command trying to run from the root. Try using from nodemodules of the current project.

```
/node_modules/.bin/cypress run
```

This will open and run the cypress. Let me know still you are facing issues.

Comment: Thank you so much , at least you tried to answer without down voting question, I will try this and revert to you as soon as possible. Can we also set default path/environment variable for  cypress so that we don`t have to pass this path in command

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps late answer, but still:

I had this errors mostly because of the version mismatch between docker image specified in Dockerfile or docker run command: `cypress/included:8.4.0` and cypress version in project package.json which was `"cypress": "8.3.0"`

Answer (score 0):

this is for windows, sorry if its a wrong place, but i came to this topic while searching for solution:

in order to use cypress, i have downloaded a zip and placed it in **c:\Projects\cypress.zip**, **.npmrc** has this: **CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=C:\Projects\cypress\cypress.zip**, *npm install* didnt did the trick, and this thing did: **node_modules.bin\cypress install**, and than: **node_modules.bin\cypress run** or **npm run cy:open**, it really depends where from its ran.

Answer (score -1):

If you installed cypress through npm i.e **npm install cypress**, then follow the instructions displayed after a complete installation. Which in my case said, *You can now open Cypress by running:* **node_modules/.bin/cypress open**. This command should be run if you are running Cypress for the first time, whereby Cypress will create and Verify its location in **~/Library/Caches/Cypress/6.2.0/Cypress.app** path. Then you will be able to open it again by running **npx cypress open** command in the terminal. Otherwise, download and install the desktop version from [here](https://download.cypress.io/desktop).